# Time Axis Values Incorrect in some ggplot plots but not others

Tags: r, ggplot2

Forum,

This is what my data looks like:

```
> data.cvg
Source: local data frame [938 x 5]

                  Date    Day                Time                 Parameter  Value
                (time) (fctr)              (time)                     (chr)  (dbl)
1  2016-03-05 01:35:03    Sat 2016-03-06 01:35:03 TerminalGarageUtilization 35.367
2  2016-03-05 01:40:01    Sat 2016-03-06 01:40:01 TerminalGarageUtilization 35.350
3  2016-03-05 01:43:18    Sat 2016-03-06 01:43:18 TerminalGarageUtilization 35.350
4  2016-03-05 01:45:01    Sat 2016-03-06 01:45:01 TerminalGarageUtilization 35.350
5  2016-03-05 01:50:02    Sat 2016-03-06 01:50:02 TerminalGarageUtilization 35.333
..                 ...    ...                 ...                       ...    ...
```

A new datapoint is generated every 5 seconds.

If I use this code, the plot correctly prints the data values, as well as the time axis. Notice, at the time of writing this post, the last datapoint is at Mar 7th, 1:50AM EST, marked by the red line ('Mon').

```
ggplot(data.cvg)+geom_line(aes(x=Time,y=TerminalGarageUtilization,color=Day))
```

[image: Correct x axis labels]

If I attempt at re-formatting the x-axis:

```
 ggplot(data.cvg)+geom_line(aes(x=Time,y=TerminalGarageUtilization,color=Day))
+scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%H:%M",date_breaks = '2 hours')
```

I get wrong x axis labels:
[image: Wrong x axis labels]

This plot **incorrectly** labels the x-axis from 5:00a to 5:00a. Notice the same Red line, but how it's marked against 5a-7a.

Why is this?

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: `scale_x_datetime` has a `limits` argument

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show limited time range on x-axis with ggplot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35680223/show-limited-time-range-on-x-axis-with-ggplot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

The answer was to also include the timezone. Correct working code:

```
library(scales)  


ggplot(data.cvg)+geom_line(aes(x=Time,y=TerminalGarageUtilization,color=Day))+
    scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = '2 hours',labels = date_format("%H:%M",tz = "EST"))
```