# Bug with ggplot2 scale_x_datetime

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an annoying bug with `scale_x_datetime` ...

```
plt = ggplot() + geom_line(data=d, aes(Time, d[, 2]), color=col) +
        scale_x_datetime(breaks = seq(d[1,1],d[dim(d)[1],1],interval*60))
```

Produces a correct time stamp on the plot at the specified intervals... However, if I add `date_labels = "%m-%d %H:%M"` to format the way the time stamp gets printed on the plot, suddenly the hour value is off by 5 hours...

The following code produces the wrong hour value on the plot

```
plt = ggplot() + geom_line(data=d, aes(Time, d[, 2]), color=col) +
        scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%m-%d %H:%M",
                         breaks = seq(d[1,1],d[dim(d)[1],1],interval*60))
```

For the sake of reproducability...

```
d = data.frame(Time = as.POSIXct(seq(1446871740, 1446893340, 60), origin = "1970-01-01"),
               Value = rnorm(361))
interval = floor(as.numeric(difftime(d[dim(d)[1],1], d[1,1], units="mins")) / 3)
col = "red"
```

Comment: This has to do with the time zone, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35836587/time-axis-values-incorrect-in-some-ggplot-plots-but-not-others).  This has been fixed in the development version [ggplot2_2.1.0.9001](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/NEWS.md).

Comment: Add this as a solution, and I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a timezone issue.  In versions of ggplot2 prior to *ggplot2_2.2.0* you would need to set the timezone when you set the labels in `scale_x_datetime`.

```
scale_x_datetime(labels = scales::date_format("%m-%d %H:%M", tz = "America/Los_Angeles")
```

This is no longer an issue for *ggplot2_2.2.0*.  From the [news](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/NEWS.md):

> scale_*_datetime() now supports time zones. It will use the timezone
>   attached to the variable by default, but can be overridden with the
>   timezone argument.

Updating your ggplot2 to the current version will solve the time shifting issue for your second plot.  If you want to set a different timezone, there is now a `timezone` argument to `scale_*_datetime`.