# ggplot2 timeseries plotting, wrong x-axis labelling

Tags: r, ggplot2

I got a problem with the x-axis labelling of my timeseries using ggplot2.

After reading plenty of posts (e.g. this one: [Time Axis Values Incorrect in some ggplot plots but not others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35836587/time-axis-values-incorrect-in-some-ggplot-plots-but-not-others)) and trying their solutions, I still don´t get the x-axis right (also after installing the latest version of ggplot2 library("ggplot2", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.4") ).

I manage to create this plot so far: 
[Daily activity pattern of individuals averaged over a month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRFFq.png)

As you can see I plotted the same data over 2 days, in order to make the activity during night better visible.
I want to keep the labelling in a %H:%M manner.
The problem seems to be in this line:
scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = '6 hours',expand = c(0,0), labels = date_format("%H:%M", tz= "UTC") )
If I use the labels = date_format("%H:%M", tz= "UTC") argument, I get a wrong x-axis labelling. Using the argument the labelling goes from 22:00 to 22:00, although it should be from 00:00 to 00:00.

I would be really greatful for solutions. 
Here the code for the [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IwMFGuYX2-qknBYcbhgH7hWUkmi0f9OG/view?usp=sharing) and the plot.

```
activitydata$year <- as.numeric(year(activitydata$ts)) 
activitydata$month <- as.numeric(month(activitydata$ts))
activitydata$day <- as.numeric(day(activitydata$ts))
activitydata$hour <- as.numeric(hour(activitydata$ts))

activitydata <- data.table(activitydata)[order(animal_id, hour),,]

activitydata_day <- group.CI(act_xy_ma2 ~ month + hour + animal_id, data = activitydata, ci = 0.95)

activitydata_day$animal_id <- as.factor(activitydata_day$animal_id)

activitydata_day$h <- as.POSIXct(paste(activitydata_day$hour, "00:00", sep = ":"), format = "%H:%M:%S", origin="1970-01-01") 

activitydata_day <- as.data.table(activitydata_day)

activitydata_day2 <- activitydata_day
activitydata_day2$h <- activitydata_day2$h + (60*60*24) 

activitydata_day3 <- activitydata_day2[hour == 0]
activitydata_day3$h <- activitydata_day3$h + (60*60*24)

activitydata_day <- rbindlist(list(activitydata_day, activitydata_day2, activitydata_day3))

titl <- paste("Daily activity pattern averaged over month", 3, sep = " ")

ggplot() + 
geom_line (data = activitydata_day[animal_id == 103 & month == 3], aes(x=h, y = act_xy_ma2.mean, col= animal_id), size = 1) +                   
scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = '6 hours',expand = c(0,0), labels = date_format("%H:%M", tz= "UTC") ) +
ggtitle(titl) + xlab("Hour of the day") + ylab("Mean acceleration rate") +
scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Paired") +
scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired") + 
theme_minimal()
```

In order to make my question hopefully more reproducible, here the R output created with dput():

```
structure(list(animal_tag = c("103_2299", "103_2299", "103_2299", 
"103_2299", "103_2299", "103_2299"), ts = structure(c(1172703600, 
1172703900, 1172704200, 1172704500, 1172704800, 1172705100), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), act_x = c(12L, 23L, 17L, 26L, 25L, 18L), act_y = c(16L, 
33L, 26L, 41L, 51L, 19L), act_xy = c(28L, 56L, 43L, 67L, 76L, 
37L), act_xy_ma2 = c(42L, 50L, 55L, 72L, 56L, 54L), animal_id = c(103L, 
103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L), tag_code = c("2299", "2299", "2299", 
"2299", "2299", "2299"), threshold_period = c("2007-09", "2007-09", 
"2007-09", "2007-09", "2007-09", "2007-09"), year = c(2007, 2007, 
2007, 2007, 2007, 2007), month = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), day = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), hour = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("animal_tag", 
"ts", "act_x", "act_y", "act_xy", "act_xy_ma2", "animal_id", 
"tag_code", "threshold_period", "year", "month", "day", "hour"
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000006220788>)
```

Comment: Seems like a timezone issue. You could try putting in your own time zone into `date_format()` instead of "UTC" or define "UTC" as the time zone in your datetime variable.

Comment: Also it may be simplest to use `date_labels = "%H:%M"` instead of `labels`.

Comment: Please include your data in the question (using `dput()`, or simulated data, or reproduce the problem using a dataset built into R) rather than as a google drive link.  It is easier for people to answer if they can simply copy/paste your code and reproduce the problem. Also, links can break over time, making the question less useful to people with similar problems in the future.

Comment: Unbelievable, I expected it to be easily solved, but that?!...  date_labels did the trick. Thanks a lot aosmith.